# Can't find error in pixel searching algorithm

Tags: c++, windows, screenshot, rgb, pixel

Ok, I'm trying to make a program that finds the position of a colored pixel within the desktop. To do this I make a screenshot of the desktop then go through the pixels and search for the one that has the matching RGB as i need. The only problem is that my program returs strange coordonates X,Y for the found pixel...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <atlimage.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct rgbcolor{
    int red;
    int green;
    int blue;} myColor;
struct point{
        int x;
        int y;
    };
point SearchPixel(int r,int g, int b){
    CImage bitmapzor;
    bitmapzor.Load(("C:\\1.bmp"));
    COLORREF PixColor=0; //This is a color data
    int R=0,G=0,B=0; //These are the channel values
    BYTE* byteptr = (BYTE*)bitmapzor.GetBits();
    int ok=0;
    int pitch = bitmapzor.GetPitch(); //This is a pointer offset to get new line of the bitmap
    //Go through every pixel and compare the RGB code
    for (int i=0; i<bitmapzor.GetWidth();i++)
        for (int j=0; j<bitmapzor.GetHeight();j++)
        {
            B= *(byteptr+pitch*j+3*i);
            G= *(byteptr+pitch*j+3*i+1);
            R= *(byteptr+pitch*j+3*i+2);       
            if(R==r&&G==g&&B==b)
            { point p;
              p.x=i;
              p.y=j;
              cout<<"First pixel found at:\n X:"<<p.x<<"\n Y:"<<p.y<<"\n-----------------\n";
              return p; 
            }
        }
    bitmapzor.Destroy(); //destroy the bitmap
    point p;
    p.x=-1;
    p.y=-1;
    cout<<"Pixel not found!\n";
    return p;

}

bool ScreenCapture(int x, int y, int width, int height, char *filename){
   // get a DC compat. w/ the screen
   HDC hDc = CreateCompatibleDC(0);    

   // make a bmp in memory to store the capture in
   HBITMAP hBmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap(GetDC(0), width, height);   

   // join em up
   SelectObject(hDc, hBmp);   

   // copy from the screen to my bitmap
    BitBlt(hDc, 0, 0, width, height, GetDC(0), x, y, SRCCOPY); 
       CImage image;
        image.Attach(hBmp);
        image.Save(("C:\\1.bmp"), Gdiplus::ImageFormatBMP);
      SearchPixel(myColor.red,myColor.green,myColor.blue);

   // free the bitmap memory
   DeleteObject(hBmp);  

   return 1;
   }

int main()
{   //RGB for the searched color
    myColor.red=200;
    myColor.green=191;
    myColor.blue=231;

    int count=0;
    while(true){
        ScreenCapture(0, 0, 1366, 768, "c:\\1.bmp");
            count++;
        cout<<"Number of searches:"<<count<<"\n\n";
        Sleep(500);
    }
   system("pause");
   return 0;    
}
```

Comment: Strange coordinates? Have you considered that you're looking through hundreds of thousands of pixels and the chances of one pixel having the same RGB value as another is pretty good? PS - You should try to format the code and the question in such a way that we might not need to run and trace the app to try and find an error.

Comment: Exactly what "strange" numbers come out? and what do you expect them to be?

Comment: To test my program I created a PAINT document with the color i was looking for inside. When Paint is minimized no pixel is found, but when I maximize it it finds a pixel with that color but in a totaly awkard position. Sometimes it finds the Y coordinate right, sometimes none of them...

@mvds It should return the position of the first pixel that has the values given (  myColor.red=200;
 myColor.green=191;
 myColor.blue=231; ) ...

Comment: As well as what @Paul suggested, the code should not contain extraneous material - like the square searching stuff.

Comment: @cristy: that much is clear, **but what numbers are returned and what numbers do you expect**?

Comment: Ok, let me edit a bit the code..

Comment: I must admit I'm totally not into this windows stuff, but googling around it seems that 1) `CImage.GetHeight()` may return a negative value, indicating that you have the pixels upside down and 2) you might get a pointer to the end of the pixel buffer. (even more glad I'm not into this windows stuff)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally I found a mistake that I think is the cause of this problem.

The pointer arithmetics:

```
        B= *(byteptr+pitch*j+3*i);
        G= *(byteptr+pitch*j+3*i+1);
        R= *(byteptr+pitch*j+3*i+2);
```

Are done for 24bits images, but the screenshot is a 32bits image that means I have to change the multiplier to 4 insteand of 3. That means:

```
    B= *(byteptr+pitch*j+4*i);
    G= *(byteptr+pitch*j+4*i+1);
    R= *(byteptr+pitch*j+4*i+2);
```

I think... I'll be back with an edit if this works or not.

EDIT: Yes **it works**, it gives the corect pixel position. Thanks everyone for your help :) .

Answer (score 2):

Well, this code could be simplified quite a lot, but first I'd suggest you try a much, much simpler case, like finding a known integer in a *small* array of integers. Once you have that working, move up to more complex cases.

**EDIT:**
You have enough knowledge to do this? Cristy, please don't take this the wrong way, but of all the programmers I've had to deal with, the worst have been the ones who thought they had nothing to learn. I didn't actually look for the bug in your code because your code is overcomplicated, and if you had gone from simple to complex when building it, you would have caught your error a lot sooner.

Comment: I don't understand? I've been learning C++ for 2 years, I've already made a C++ game so I have enough knowladge to do this.

Comment: Actually the code is a simple as it can get. This is the fastest method to get a pixel color (GetPixel is very slow) , and the searching algorithm is simply a linear search.I wrote in my answear, the error I made was because when I used example bmps (without screenshot) they were 24bits, and when i used screeshots they were 32bits so the position of each pixel would be stored in a diffrent place in the memory (diffrent pointers) .

Trust me, I've done more searching algorithms then you may have seen , each for duzin of times... (heap sort, liniear sort, bubble sort, quick sort, etc...) Thanks!

Comment: @Cristy: really? Because I was able to simplify it quite a lot (using the same method to get a pixel color). But hey, I'll trust you, you clearly have nothing to learn, and I'm pleased to meet someone who has done all the search algorithms I've done (A*, simplex, simulated annealing, least-action, Bayes, etc.) Bye!

Comment: Hi @Beta, this question recently popped up in my inbox (because someone edited it) and I didn't remember what it was about, so I read the question and answers again. I want to say I'm sorry for being rude to you, I can't believe the words above came from me. Sorry again :) (in my defense, it was my first question ever on SO :) )

Comment: @Cristy: No sweat, I was a beginner once too.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you print out the RGB values of the first few pixel to make sure you're even grabbing the pixel data correctly.  If your offsets are wrong, you'll never get this to work.